# Sub query did not connected to main query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Below query is used to retrieve records from database to shown in report. But the SENOKO  AND EUNOS column show **duplicate** total in every row. This seems the **subquery did not connected to the main query** causes the filtering is not taken.

```
SELECT whbal.customer, customer.imp_license_no, customer.psq_level, 
       (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3),(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_good) + CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_slack)) * CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.std_weight) / 1000)) 
        FROM whbal WHERE warehouse='SKW') AS SENOKO
       (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3),(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_good) + CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_slack)) * CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.std_weight) / 1000)) 
        FROM whbal WHERE warehouse='EKW') AS EUNOS
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN whbal ON whbal.customer=customer.customer AND whbal.date_create<=@date1                   
INNER JOIN stktype ON whbal.stock_type=stktype.stock_type
WHERE whbal.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2 AND whbal.stock_type=@type
GROUP BY whbal.customer, customer.customer, customer.imp_license_no, customer.psq_level
```

Result:

[image]

Do anyone know what is the problem and solution, please comment and guide.
Appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Or, alternatively, the data produces the same results for both `warehouse = 'SKW'` and `warehouse = 'EKW'`.  If you provide a small data sample and show the results, that would be helpful, as would having a table alias on all columns, including `warehouse`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please refer to my edited question. The EUNOS column is located at most right hand beside SENOKO column. Thanks

Comment: you did nothing to link the subquery to anything in your main query ... why should there be any connection?

Comment: I have try to connect them but he result still the same:


    FROM whbal INNER JOIN customer ON         whbal.customer=customer.customer WHERE warehouse='SKW' AND whbal.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2) AS SENOKO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, your problem is simple.  Your query is simply not correlated to the outer query, so you are getting the total for `Senkoku` (and presumably `EUNO`) across the entire `whbal` table.

Reading your query, I figured that this was what you wanted.

I think you need a correlation clause in the subquery, where you tie the rows in `whbal` to some column in one of the outer tables.  Not knowing what you really want or your data structure, I can't propose a particular condition.

EDIT:

The correct way to connect them would be:

```
   (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3),(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_good) + CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_slack)) * CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.std_weight) / 1000)) 
    FROM whbal
    WHERE warehouse = 'SKW' and whbal.customer = customer.customer
   ) AS SENOKO
```

Comment: I have try to connect them but he result still the same: FROM whbal INNER JOIN customer ON whbal.customer=customer.customer WHERE warehouse='SKW' AND whbal.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2) AS SENOKO